# every bootstrap modal repeat same id in laravel with ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

i wrote some code to view my all showing events details using bootstrap modal popup when click read more button. but when i click read more button every response repeats same id.
this is my laravel code

```
@if(!empty($event))
    @foreach($event as $value)
       <!-- Single Blog Post -->
       <div class="single-blog-post d-flex" id="event_tag">
       <div class="post-thumbnail">
       <img src="{{asset('images/'.$value->image)}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="post-content">
         <a class="post-title">
            @if(strlen($value->title) <= 35)
               {{$value->title}}
            @else
            {{substr($value->title, 0, 35) . '...'}}
            @endif
            </a>
            <div class="post-meta d-flex justify-content-between">
            <center><button id="event_button" class="post-cata cata-sm cata-success text_white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button></center>
             </div>
            </div>
         <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id" value="{{$value->id}}"></div>
         @endforeach
       @endif
```

and this is javascript code to get id and show every id detail.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#event_button", function() {      
    var id = $("event_id").val();
    console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/event/" + id + "/show",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(html) {
      $("#event_title").html(html.data.title);          
  }
});
})
</script>
```

every time repeats id no 2 when click each event read more button. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some mistakes in html too. For example, has fixes ids in html.
'event_id'
'event_button'...

Try this...

```
<button id="event_button-{!! $value->id !!}" data-target="event_id-{!! $value->id !!}" 
<input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id-{!! $value->id !!}"
```

The code above will fixed the id issue.

Now let's to the JS code... Change the click event:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.post-cata", function() {      
    var id = $("#" . $(this).data("target").val();
    ...
```

Do you need to associate tags to work with the right value. Avoid to put fixes ids inside a php loop. The html id element must be unique in document.

So, has many ways to do this. In this case, the input hidden fild is not necessary. you can put the id in a attribute in the button tag too.

```
<button data-id="{!! $value->id !!}...
```

So in the jquery click event do:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

It's more ease and clean.

Answer (score 0):

give class name to button and add attribute to button

```
<button  class="event_button post-cata cata-sm cata-success text_white" data-eventid="{{$value->id}}">Read More</button>
```

so no need to use hidden input id

now using jQuery :

```
$(document).on('click','.event_button',function(){
     var event_id = $(this).attr("data-eventid");
      $("#myModal").modal("show");
      $.ajax({
        url: "/event/" + event_id+ "/show",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(html) {

          $("#event_title").html(html.data.title);          
        }
     });
});
```